# Poisson algebra automorphisms of a symplectic manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold. Let $V=\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ be the Lie algebra of smooth real valued functions. Suppose $f:\rightarrow V$ be an Lie-algebra isomorphism (an algebra isomorphism that preservs the Lie bracket).

**1) Does $f$ is always induced by a morphism of $M$?**

**2) If not, what are the obstructions?**

PS 2: Any kind of reference will be helpful.
PS 1): If the question not apt for Mathoverflow, please provide references or links before downvoting.

Comment: The following paper, together with its bibliography, should be of interest to you http://www.impan.pl/~jagrab/grabowski.pdf